"AttributeError: module 'myApp.app' has no attribute 'run'" when trying to run a Flask application with uWSGI
I have a Flask app utilizing Blueprints which runs in a virtual environment (venv).
The app has a structure
myApp
├── app
│   ├── about
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── routes.py
│   ├── extensions.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── routes.py
│   ├── models
│   │   ├── contact.py
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── myApp.css
│   │   ├── favicon-16x16.png
│   └── templates
│       ├── about
│       │   └── index.html
│       ├── base.html
│       └── index.html
├── bin
│   ├── activate
│   ├── flask
│   ├── pip
│   ├── python -> python3.12
│   ├── python3 -> python3.12
│   ├── python3.12 -> /usr/bin/python3.12
│   ├── uwsgi
│   └── wheel
├── config.py
├── myApp.db
├── myApp -> /home/janeDoe/myApp
├── myApp.ini
├── include
│   └── ...
├── lib
│   └── ...
├── lib64 -> lib
├── pyvenv.cfg
├── requirements.txt
└── wsgi.py

If I execute
cd /home/janeDoe/myApp
flask run

the page renders fine.
If I try to run with uwsgi as in
cd /home/janeDoe/myApp
uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:5000 --protocol=http -w wsgi:app

where
wsgi.py:

from myApp import app
app.run()

and
app/__init__.py:

from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from app.extensions import db
from flask_favicon import FlaskFavicon

def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)

    # Initialize Flask extensions here
    db.init_app(app)

    # Register blueprints here
    from app.main import bp as main_bp

    app.register_blueprint(main_bp)

    from app.about import bp as about_bp

    app.register_blueprint(about_bp, url_prefix="/about")

    flaskFavicon = FlaskFavicon()
    flaskFavicon.init_app(app)
    flaskFavicon.register_favicon("app/static/favicon-16x16.png", "default")

    @app.route("/test/")
    def test_page():
        return "<h1>Testing the Flask Application Factory Pattern</h1>"

    return app

I get
...

mapped 72920 bytes (71 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/JaneDoe/myApp/wsgi.py", line 5, in <module>
    app.run()
    ^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'myApp.app' has no attribute 'run'
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 1321333, cores: 1)

I would have thought app.run() would be imported from flask in app/__init__.py when create_app is invoked. What do I need to change to have app.run() recognized?

Because of the __init__.py in the app directory, the import statement from myApp import app means that you're importing the entire folder as a module, or package (see the Python documentation).
Additionally, since create_app is a function, there is no way that the return value would be available for use in wsgi.py unless it is called.
The Flask documentation contains a practical example that you can refer to and adapt. However, in your case, make the following change in wsgi.py:
from app import create_app

# This makes the return value of `create_app` available
# for use in wsgi.py
app = create_app()

I haven't tested this on my end (uWSGI on Windows problems) but it should work.

Unfortunately, that didn't work:

mapped 145840 bytes (142 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***

Serving Flask app 'app'
Debug mode: on
Address already in use
Port 5000 is in use by another program. Either identify and stop that program, or start the server with a different port.


Looks like it creates another instance and tries to bind it to port 5000.

In that case, you'll need to remove the line app.run().

[SOLVED} That was it! Runs correctly. Thank you so much for your help!

Edited the answer to delete app.run() from the code.
